# How can I confirm that the Imagetragick vulnerability is fixed on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, heroku, imagemagick

I'm trying to double confirm for a client that the Imagetragick vuln is indeed fixed on heroku. I don't want to just trust that heroku's released statement is true, I would like to confirm myself.

I'm using mini_magick and carrierwave on a rails app, but this should work for any setup that uses imagemagick (paperclip, etc...)

heroku's statement: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/891

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it's relatively easy to confirm by looking at the policy.xml document on your heroku server. The only fancy bit is knowing where to look. So do the following (remember you are in a production environment so don't go editing any files; and they'd be overwritten eventually anyway):

```
heroku run bash [-a] [app name if needed]

find / | grep "policy.xml" (not really necessary, just showing my work)

cat /etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml
```

it should display the following:

```
<policymap>
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="EPHEMERAL" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="URL" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MVG" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MSL" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="TEXT" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="SHOW" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="WIN" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PLT" />
</policymap>
```

You can then confirm that against the fix:

https://imagetragick.com/

which is the following:

```
<policymap>
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="EPHEMERAL" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="URL" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MVG" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MSL" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="TEXT" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="SHOW" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="WIN" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PLT" />
</policymap>
```

Comment: What if I actually need to convert https:// image locations? I am trying to override the rule to rights="read | write" but it seems that the default policy at /etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml takes more precedent

Comment: @MattKim Did you figure this out? running into the same issue with https...

Comment: hey @tehfailsafe I just ended up using aws and spinning up my own server. If you do have a resolution, I'd love to hear what you did!

Answer (score 0):

The actual way to confirm that the vulnerability is fixed, is by executing the POC exploit on the target. The official disclosure [here](https://imagetragick.com/) also shows a way to easily test the server by executing the following commands in your terminal.

*(**git** should be installed on the server or download the contents of the git manually.)*

**Commands**

```
git clone https://github.com/ImageTragick/PoCs
cd PoCs
chmod +x test.sh && ./test.sh
```

**Safe Output**

This output means that your server is no longer vulnerable.

```
user@host:~/code/PoCs$ ./test.sh 
testing read
SAFE

testing delete
SAFE

testing http with local port: 38663
SAFE

testing http with nonce: a7DyBeV7
SAFE

testing rce1
SAFE

testing rce2
SAFE

testing MSL
SAFE
```

**Unsafe Output**

If you see the *UNSAFE* word anywhere in the output, your server is still vulnerable.

```
user@host:~/code/PoCs$ ./test.sh 
testing read
UNSAFE

testing delete
UNSAFE

testing http with local port: 44755
UNSAFE

testing http with nonce: a7DvBer2
UNSAFE

testing rce1
UNSAFE

testing rce2
UNSAFE

testing MSL
UNSAFE
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I'm not going to execute any scripts inside the heroku shell. This was specifically for validating on heroku and not other platforms. I do agree that would be the ideal way to confirm, but I don't think it will work on heroku.